# Trouble on changing the default primary key for a database table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, primary-key

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to change the default primary key for a SQL database table from `id` to `account_id`. *The `account_id` statement and behavior should be the same of `id`* (auto-increment, unique, ...).

In my migration file I tryed the following:

```
create_table :users, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :account_id
  ...

  t.timestamps
end
add_index :users, :account_id, :primary => true
```

But using [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/), when I try to edit the 'users' table, I get this error:

```
'users': table is not editable because there is no primary key defined for the table
```

So, **how can I set properly the primary key for my 'users' table?**

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750413/altering-the-primary-key-in-rails-to-be-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_table

There is a :primary_key option for changing the primary key column