# ActiveRecord Migrations : Postgres : Strings as primary keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have tried several ways to add string as a primary key in rails. So far, this is what I have tried. Can someone please help find the solution.

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients, primary_key: :client_id, id: false do |t|
      t.string :client_id
      t.string :client_secret
      t.integer :app_id
    end
    add_index :clients, [:app_id, :client_id]
  end
end
```

--

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients, id: false do |t|
      t.string :client_id, primary: true
      t.string :client_secret
      t.integer :app_id
    end
    add_index :clients, [:app_id, :client_id]
  end
end
```

--

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients, id: false do |t|
      t.string :client_id, primary_key: true
      t.string :client_secret
      t.integer :app_id
    end
    add_index :clients, [:app_id, :client_id]
  end
end
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) Why make an id column a string? 2) Why make a string a primary key instead of just unique?

Comment: Have you looked at anything over here http://stackoverflow.com/q/750413/479863 ?