# how to make ID a random 8 digit alphanumeric in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is something I am using inside my model

This is the URL that gets posted to another 3rd party website through API

Post Model (post.rb)

```
"#{content.truncate(200)}...more http://domain.com/post/#{id.to_s}"
```

The "id" is referring to the post id. How can I convert that into a random 8 digit alphanumeric?

Right now, it gets displayed as something that people can alter `http://domain.com/post/902`

I want `http://domain.com/post/9sd98asj`

I know I probably need to use something like `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8)` but where and how can I set this up?

This is what I have in routes.rb

```
match '/post/:id', :to => 'posts#show', via: :get, as: :post
```

Comment: `to_s` inside interpolation is redundant.

Comment: If you want a random number, then `id` is irrelevant.

Comment: how can I replace the id with a random number while keeping the path working properly? here's what I have in routes.rb: `match '/post/:id', :to => 'posts#show', via: :get, as: :post`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You only need to add one attribute to `post`. The attribute name is `permalink`.

Try running:

```
rails g migration add_permalink_to_posts permalink:string
rake db:migrate
```

You have two[Active Record Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) you can choose from: `before_save` or `before_create` (review the difference between both). This example is using the `before_save` callback.

***note : for Rails 3.x***

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :permalink
  before_save :make_it_permalink

 def make_it_permalink
   # this can create a permalink using a random 8-digit alphanumeric
   self.permalink = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8)
 end

end
```

[urlsafe_base64](http://apidock.com/ruby/SecureRandom/urlsafe_base64/class)

And in your `routes.rb` file:

```
match "/post/:permalink" => 'posts#show', :as => "show_post"
```

In `posts_controller.rb`:

```
def index
 @posts = Post.all
end

def show
  @post = Post.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
end
```

Finally, here are the views (`index.html.erb`):

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<p><%= truncate(post.content, :length => 300).html_safe %>
   <br/><br/>
   <%= link_to "Read More...", show_post_path(post.permalink) %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: instead of displaying the final link using view, any idea how I can use the URL inside a model? Here's what I'm trying to put into the model instead of into the view...`"#{content.truncate(200)}...more http://domain.com/post/#{permalink}"`

Comment: this is the error that I get `undefined method 'permalink=' for #<Post:0x55403a0>`

Comment: @user2159586, you need to add this new field to `attr_accessible`, also you need to migrate at first.

Comment: @BillyChan, I see. So I need to create a new column inside the post table called 'permalink' and make it `attr_accessible`?

Answer (score 3):

"[Altering the primary key in Rails to be a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750413/altering-the-primary-key-in-rails-to-be-a-string)" is related to your question.

I would:

- Leave default ID on table
- Not define resources routes, writing the needed ones with match (like `match '/post/:code'`)
- On `controller#show`, use `Post.find_by_code(params[:code])`.