# Using alpha-numeric slugs instead of ids in routes - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, slug, alphanumeric

I am building a Rails 5 team management app which lets users manage organizations and users. I would like to be able to change from using the :id in the path (e.g: `/organizations/43`) and use an alpha-numeric slug instead (e.g: `/organizations/H6Y47Nr7`). Similar to how Trello do this (i.e: `https://trello.com/b/M9X71pE6/board-name`). Is there an easy way of doing this?

I have seen the [FriendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem which could take care of the slugging in the path but what would be the best way to generate the slug in the first place?

Ideally, for the most *bang for buck* the slug would include A-Z, a-z and 0-9 (as I understand it, this is Base58?) and for the sake of not blowing out the url too much, 8 characters at the most. If my calculations are correct, this gives 218 trillion combinations, which should be plenty.

Am I on the right track? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can check [hashids](https://github.com/peterhellberg/hashids.rb) gem which support customizing number of character and character to be included in slug. I recently made a rails [plugin](https://github.com/sajan45/hashids_activerecord) for that but I have not used either of them in production yet.

Comment: Take a look my old answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16096646/1297435

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a slug, easiest way is to use `SecureRandom`.  You can add something like the following in your model

```
before_create :generate_slug

private

def generate_slug
  begin
    self.slug = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8)
  end while Organization.exists?(slug: slug)
end
```

One small caveat here with respect to what you want is that the slug will sometimes contain an underscore or a dash but that should be fine.

```
irb(main):014:0> SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8)
=> "HlHHV_6rN3k"
irb(main):015:0> SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8)
=> "naRqT-NmYDU"
irb(main):016:0> SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8)
=> "9h04l4jEEsM"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could I not just use `SecureRandom.base58(8)` instead? It returns something like `KBz4i9ux`.

Comment: Also, what about handling collisions? Or does `SecureRandom` take care of it? Thanks again!

Comment: not familiar with `base58`.  The reason why I used `urlsafe_base64` is because you need a url-safe string.  As for collisions, there's a very small chance of race condition happening but I wouldn't worry about it

Comment: I see. Thanks. As I understand it, base58 is similar to base64 except it omits punctuation and ambiguous characters (i.e: 0 and O, and I and l) so still URL safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you go that route, I would create a table were you save the slugs that you are generating and don't delete them even when you delete an organization. When you create a new organization query this model to make sure there are no duplicates slugs. Also add a unique index in the slug column of the organizations table.

You should not give up the id column with integers so in the show method you will need to do:

```
org = Organization.where(slug: params[:id]).first
```