# Migration isn't listening when creating a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have the following migration and it's still creating a primary key `:id` as an integer. Is there a reason why this would be happening?

```
create_table :offers, :id => :false do |t|
  t.string :id, :limit => 36, :primary => true
  t.string :app_id
  t.integer :bid
  t.boolean :active, :default => false
  t.timestamps
end
```

Here's the console output

```
-- create_table(:offers, {:id=>:false})
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "offers_id_seq" for serial column "offers.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "offers_pkey" for table "offers"
   -> 0.0047s
```

Comment: Your answer can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750413/altering-the-primary-key-in-rails-to-be-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer. Should be `false` not `:false`.