# Rails: Best way to stub out a model with a string ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, rails-models, rails-generate

Say I want to stub out a Product model which will have a `product_id` field of type string.

Do I add `product_id` in addition to the default `id` field that Rails creates?<sup>1</sup>

```
rails g model product product_id:string:uniq
```

Or make `product_id` the primary key?

```
rails g model product product_id:primary_key
```

With the latter option, is there anything else to set up in addition or should it work right away?<sup>2</sup> And would storage and retrieval be as simple as:

```
Product.create product_id: "54c31h"
Product.find("54c31h")
```

---

1. Note that I didn't put `:index:uniq`. This is because `:uniq` on its own creates a unique index (i.e. in the schema you would see `add_index :products, :product_id, unique: true`).
2. Looks like there are some extra steps:

   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15297616/72321
   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6714889/72321