# How can I get Rails 5 to play nicely with a primary key that has a period in it?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm working with a database I have no control over, and cannot make alterations to. This database has a table called **warehouse_items**. Each warehouse item is uniquely identified by a primary key indicating the item id.

Unfortunately, that primary key attribute is named **WAREHOUSE_ITEM.ID**

(Note the obnoxious period between "item" and "id")

---

When I try to run a basic query, such as:

```
WarehouseItem.find('wh3453')
```

I get an *Undefined Table* error.

Fortunately, when looking at what Rails is attempting to do, the problem becomes obvious:

```
: SELECT  "warehouse_items".* FROM "warehouse_items" WHERE "WAREHOUSE_ITEM"."ID" = $1 LIMIT $2
```

Because of the period in the attribute name, Rails is treating "WAREHOUSE_ITEM.ID" as a table/attribute combination, rather than an attribute name with a period in it.

When I run the following PSQL query by hand, I get exactly what I need:

```
SELECT  "warehouse_items".* FROM "warehouse_items" WHERE "warehouse_items"."WAREHOUSE_ITEM.ID" = 'wh3453'
```

Why is Rails screwing this up, and how can I fix it?

---

**EDIT:**

Also worth noting: I've tried using `self.primary_key` to override the primary key to no avail.

I've tried both a string and a symbol, as in:

```
self.primary_key="WAREHOUSE_ITEM.ID"
```

and

```
self.primary_key=:"WAREHOUSE_ITEM.ID"
```

Neither one has worked...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override the default primary key column in ruby on rails 4.0.+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35731467/how-to-override-the-default-primary-key-column-in-ruby-on-rails-4-0)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've tried using both `self.primary_key="WAREHOUSE_ITEM.ID"` and `self.primary_key=:"WAREHOUSE_ITEM.ID"` (i.e. as a string and as a symbol) to no avail.

Comment: There is another solution I have seen used (not  Activerecord but with other orm tools) but might be a no-go given your initial statement; you could create a *view* in the database to the base table in question and alias the column to have the expected `Id` name.

Comment: Again, I don't have control over the primary database, annoying as that is.

However, your comment has made me wonder if I could use a Rails alias to the same effect. I'll try and report back!

Comment: Have you tried `WarehouseItem.find_by("WAREHOUSE_ITEM.ID" => "wh3453")` or even `WarehouseItem.find_by_sql(the_sql_that_works)`. If either of those queries works, you can abstract them into a `WarehouseItem#custom_find` method

Comment: You can use Arel to construct the query `WarehouseItem.find_by(WarehouseItem.arel_table["WAREHOUSEITEM.ID"].eq(1))` - using a string won't actually work due to how rails interprets them. Unfortantely this is really just the tip of the iceberg and I don't really think you will ever get ActiveRecord to play nice with this schema.

Comment: The `find_by` method doesn't work, unfortunately. The `find_by_sql` does, however! But... I found an even better solution (that I'll post below)!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, everyone!

A suggestion in the comments to use `find_by_sql` does work! However, I stumbled onto a different solution that works even better.

First, I aliased the annoying attribute name to something simple: `id`

```
alias_attribute :id, :"WAREHOUSE_ITEM.ID"
```

Notice that it's still a symbol, which is important for the next step.

I then overwrite the `primary_key` method with a custom function:

```
  def self.primary_key
    return "id"
  end
```

Now, when I do `WarehouseItem.find('wh3453')`, Rails defaults to checking `id`, which is aliased to the correct symbol and it works as intended!!!