# I can not validate my string field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, tiny-tds

I am using rails and SQL server in a project. When I put the following validation in the model: `validates :Clave, uniqueness: true` I get this error: `can't cast ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServer::Type::Char::Data to varchar`

this is my schema.rb

```
create_table "Productos", primary_key: "Clave", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "Id",                 limit: 4,                             null: false
    t.varchar  "Producto",           limit: 255
    t.varchar  "CodBarras",          limit: 50
    t.varchar  "IdEmpresa",          limit: 50

  end
```

this is my model producto.rb

```
class Producto < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "Clave"

  validates :IdEmpresa, uniqueness: true
  validates :Clave, uniqueness: true
  validates :Producto, presence: true

end
```

Comment: `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServer::Type::Char::Data to varchar` looks like a column type error

Comment: @HarlemSquirrel Only happens with the string, with the other fields as integer does not happen

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can or need to validate primary keys. Entries without keys are not persisted in the database. Saving a new object should generate a new primary key for it.

Take a look at these posts for chaning the primary key to not be an integer:

- [Altering the primary key in Rails to be a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750413/altering-the-primary-key-in-rails-to-be-a-string#6714889)
- [Using Rails, how can I set my primary key to not be an integer-typed column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200568/using-rails-how-can-i-set-my-primary-key-to-not-be-an-integer-typed-column)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I need to validate it because when an existing primary key is inserted it shows me the red screen of rails error indicating that it exists. However if I validate it this way, I can show the errors to the user in a better way like this: <% errors.full_messages.each do | message | %>
         <Li> <% = message%> </ li>
       <% End%>

Comment: Are you trying to set the primary key based on user input?

Comment: You don't want to do that. ActiveRecord will generate the primary key for you. User input should not be used to set primary keys. Just make that user input a new column and use the default primary key `id`

Comment: I know but I am working on a previously developed project and it was previously established because the field "Clave" is like an identifier for the products

Comment: I have the same error when validating another field that is string. Apparently when you make a validates: product, uniqueness: true I get that error

Comment: What does your schema.rb and model look like?

Comment: I have updated my post with the schema and mode. I get the same error with the field "CompanyId", because it's string